# JTable row filtering based on values of two different columns that Have same data

Tags: java, swing, rowfilter

i have JTable that has a data like follow :

```
------------------------
| Name | Num 1 | Num 2 |
------------------------
| Data |    9  |  0    |
| Data |   17  |  24   |
| Data |    0  |  0    |
| Data |    0  |  5    |
------------------------
```

i have a `RowFilter` that Must be hide a Rows that Includes 0 on row `Num 1` and `Num 2` !

```
sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(((model)));

List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> rfs = new ArrayList<>(2);

String regexHider1 = "(?i)^" + "0" + "$";
String regexHider2 = "(?i)^" + "0" + "$";

rfs.add(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regexHider1, 1)));
rfs.add(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regexHider1, 2)));

RowFilter<Object, Object> af = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);

sorter.setRowFilter(af);

jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

the output was :

```
------------------------
| Name | Num 1 | Num 2 |
------------------------
| Data |   17  |  24   |
------------------------
```

but what i need is to hide if the `Num 1` And `Num 2` both Includes 0 !

What i need is like the following :

```
------------------------
| Name | Num 1 | Num 2 |
------------------------
| Data |    9  |  0    |
| Data |   17  |  24   |
| Data |    0  |  5    |
------------------------
```

Only 1 row hided because only 1 row include 0 on Bothe Num1 and Num2

Example Code :

```
package Classes;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class JTableExample {

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public RowSorter<TableModel> sortert = new TableRowSorter<>(model);

    public TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(((model)));

    public JTableExample() {

        String[] cols = {"Name", "Num 1", "Num 2"};

        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        table.setModel(model);
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(cols);

        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Data", 9, 0});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Data", 17, 24});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Data", 0, 0});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Data", 0, 5});

        JButton btn = new JButton();

        btn.setText("Filter");

        btn.addActionListener((e) -> {

            sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(((model)));

            List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> rfs = new ArrayList<>(2);

            String regexHider1 = "(?i)^" + "0" + "$";
            String regexHider2 = "(?i)^" + "0" + "$";

            rfs.add(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regexHider1, 1)));
            rfs.add(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regexHider2, 2)));

            RowFilter<Object, Object> af = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);

            sorter.setRowFilter(af);

            table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        });

        JPanel jdb = new JPanel();

        jdb.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        jdb.add(table);
        jdb.add(btn);
        jdb.add(table);

        frame.add(jdb);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JTableExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is post your frame with a JTable with hard coded data so people can test your code and attempt to rewrite the filter if they so desire.

Comment: ok i will edit it and post the full code

Comment: At least twice in the previous couple of hours you have signed into the site, presumably to check your question for answers, but you still haven't posted your MRE. I doubt you will get help until you post a proper MRE.

Comment: Also note that a [mre] is **not** *"the full code"*. Read the document carefully before making an [edit].

Comment: Now check out I made a simple example code showing the problem !

Comment: Still not an MRE. The custom editor is irrelevant to the problem and doesn't appear to do anything. Also, why do you have two sets of data for the table? The point of the MRE is to remove all irrelevant code that is not directly related to the problem so you can concentrate only on the problem without other distractions. We also only have limited time to read the code. So we don't want to be confused by unnecessary code.

Comment: I deleted the unnecessary stuff that was not related to the problem and kept an example of the problem. I provided an example and an explanation also provided the code. I do not know a better way to explain the matter. I explained the problem and put the code to display the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the "notFilter" was used in the wrong place. This seems to work:

```
List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> rfs = new ArrayList<>(2);
rfs.add(RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.EQUAL, 0, 1));
rfs.add(RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.EQUAL, 0, 2));
RowFilter<Object, Object> af = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);

sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(((model)));
sorter.setRowFilter(  RowFilter.notFilter(af) );
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

I also played around with using a custom RowFilter:

```
RowFilter<Object,Object> rf = new RowFilter<Object,Object>()
{
    public boolean include(Entry<? extends Object, ? extends Object> entry)
    {
        Integer column1 = (Integer)entry.getValue(1);
        Integer column2 = (Integer)entry.getValue(2);

        if (column1.intValue() == 0 && column2.intValue() == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
};

sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(((model)));
sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Note: in both cases the filter expects Integer data so it won't work if you edit a column and change the value to 0, because the model will be updated with a String value. I would assume your real TableModel would override the `getColumnClass()` method to return Integer.class for the last 2 columns.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you, but is there another way to add another filter for the DATA field, and the filter is of type `regexFilter` ?   Let's say hide the fields that do not contain the letter D in the first column `Name` with the filters of `num1` and `num2` Active

Comment: i tried to do this by adding `String regex = "(?i)^" + "Adeeb";` And `rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex3, 0));` after `rfs.add(RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.EQUAL, 0, 2));`  but it didnot work !

Comment: If you want more complex filtering I would suggest a custom filter is the easiest approach.  Your filter just becomes an if/else condition based on your requirements.